Given a 3D array of 0s and the index for a starting 1, generate all variants of the array in which all 1s are connected to the first by other 1s
I am writing a program to optimize the placement of components in a voxel-based game. I can handle every step except the first, which will be easiest to explain if I use a 3D array of integers (0 or 1) as an example.
Given an array, and the x, y, and z coördinates of the starting position, I need to generate every possible variant of the array, where each "1" is connected to the starting position by other "1"s.
For example, with a 3x3x3 array and the starting position at (1, 1, 1), I need to generate (in no particular order):
// Variant 1
0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0
0 0 0    0 1 0    0 0 0
0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0

// Variant 2
0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0
0 0 0    1 1 0    0 0 0
0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0

// Variant 3
0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0
0 0 0    0 1 1    0 0 0
0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0

//...
// Variant 64 (all neighbors)
0 0 0    0 1 0    0 0 0
0 1 0    1 1 1    0 1 0
0 0 0    0 1 0    0 0 0

//...
// Variant [many] (neighbors of neighbors)
0 1 0    1 1 1    0 1 0
1 1 1    1 1 1    1 1 1
0 1 0    1 1 1    0 1 0

//...
// Variant [final] (neighbors of neighbors of neighbors)
1 1 1    1 1 1    1 1 1
1 1 1    1 1 1    1 1 1
1 1 1    1 1 1    1 1 1

While emphatically not generating any variants with disconnected 1s
// Variant X
// The 1 at (1, 1, 0) is fine, but (0, 0, 0) is not connected
1 0 0    0 1 0    0 0 0
0 0 0    0 1 0    0 0 0
0 0 0    0 0 0    0 0 0

Everything I've seen and tried has involved creating random variants and then filtering for the conditions I need (i.e., no disconnected 1s), but this requires recursively checking every variant for connectedness and is hugely inefficient.
This is going to be run on arrays with dimensions up to the low double digits, so I can't afford any unnecessary cycles.

Those are not permutations. In a permutation, the number of 0 and of 1 would not change.

Am not very familiar with the terminology here. Any recommendations on the wording I should be using instead?

This can be a breadth first graph traversal algorithm problem. You start at a coordinate (x, y, z), add the start coord =1 and rest of 0s as a valid solution. Then you visit all its neighbours (add start coord and each neighbour to the solution), then for each neigbour, you add their neighbours...and so on. You probably need to use a queue. You need to mark coordinates as visited. You stop when all neigbours of the current coordinate have already been visited.  See some graph traversal  impl.e.g.
